# Excel VBA function that can recalculate on scroll

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to detect scrolling in Excel since its not possible out of the box and I used the following macro to check the row number of the top left visible cell in the active window:

```
Function Scroll() As Double

Scroll = ActiveWindow.ScrollRow

End Function
```

So in excel if I paste the formula `=Scroll()` into any cell, it actually gives me the top visible cell row. When I scroll it doesn't update but if i click on the cell, then click on formula bar and press Enter it then updates again. Is there a way around this or that's just a limitation in Excel.

Comment: Why do you wish to detect scrolling? If you wish to return to a static section of your worksheet after a scroll you might use the Worksheet_SelectionChange event to call a function like your `Scroll`, or perhaps `Window.ScrollIntoView`, to reset the view.

Comment: @Variatus I want to be able to automatically freeze/unfreeze specific rows when scrolling

Comment: That seems counter-intuitive. Freezing is supposed to persist through scrolling. Anyway, the only idea I'm able to come up with for now is to somehow hitch the SelectionChange event to your cart, there being no applicable Scroll event. Perhaps you can record the top left cell in a variable, determine if it has changed in a SelectionChange procedure, and take whatever action you want if that was the case. That would reduce the required action to a single click.

Comment: Add `Application.Volatile` at the top of your `Scroll` function. If it makes a difference you could explore ways of avoiding volatility, if such avoidance is necessary in your case.

Comment: @Variatus The spreadsheet has different headings every 100 rows or so, so when I scroll to a certain section i want the freezing to be dynamic ie reapply a freeze whenever headings come into view. `Application.Volatile` doesnt work for this case.

Comment: Take a look at this. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DetectScroll.htm

Comment: @Variatus thanks I did see that post but could n't follow it as the zip file linked was corrupt, couldn't open it

Comment: I saved the zip file to my disk and opened it from there without a problem. But even without getting access, take a look at the complexity. You might decide it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @Variatus Strange not sure why it aint opening for me. What program did you use, I tried with Winrar. And yes I will just try to look into it just for the thrill to see it work but it def wont be worth the effort for what I really wanted to use it for as the Excel file is used by various users in different locations and will be a pain trying to set every single person's machine

Comment: I downloaded the workbook ScrollEvents.xls which does come as a zip file. Frankly, I don't know off-hand which program I used for unzipping. Windows did it for me. Winrar shouldn't be the problem. Fact is, the file isn't corrupt at source. So you ought to be able to lay your hands on it, too. Take another look at the problem. It all originates from a report format that doesn't fit the screen. Offer your users buttons to switch between views and they will stop scrolling all by themselves.

Comment: @Variatus Yes I was able to open that file too, but I was talking about the SSubTmr6.dll file which is required for the scroll macro to work. Its linked in the article and it doesnt open.

Comment: It's a DLL. It needs to be installed, not opened.

Comment: @Variatus Yes but the downloaded file is in zip format so maybe the dll is inside